# What replaces Page.Trace in ASP.net Core Razor Pages?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, trace

I've only been using ASP.net Core Razor Pages on one project, so I'm still new to this; forgive me. I want to debug a webpage that I created in ASP.net Core Razor Pages that's running slowly. Whenever I use ASP.Net Webforms (which I'm infinitely more familiar with), I'll use Page Tracing and walk through the output at the bottom of the page to try and isolate any bottlenecks/slowdowns.

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/abhikumarvatsa/tracing-in-Asp-Net/ <-- what I'm looking for is something similar to the screen capture of the Trace output toward the bottom of this blog post. I don't care if it shows up on the page or in a log file, as long as it shows the output of the trace and elapsed times between the trace points the way the screen capture does.

What is this called in ASP.net Core, and where/how would I access it? I saw logging in appsettings.json as well, but no indication of where the logs are stored and whether they have what I'm looking for. Thanks.

I tried looking this up, but I'm not really sure what I'm looking for.

Comment: Have you check [What diagnostic tools are available in .NET Core?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/?WT.mc_id=ondotnet-c9-cephilli) and [dotnet-trace performance analysis utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/dotnet-trace?WT.mc_id=ondotnet-c9-cephilli)  ?